# How to make left grid column content stay during scroll?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a bootstrap grid setup with one row and two columns as shown here:

```
<div id="main">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-2 first-col">
       How to make this column fixed during scroll?
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-10 second-col">
       This contains a lot of text...
  </div>
</div>
```

It has been styled this way:

```
#main {
   height: 200px;
   overflow-y:scroll;
}

.row {
  height: 100%;
}

.first-col {
  border-right: 1px solid;
  height: 100%;
}
```

What I want is for the first column (including the border black line) to stay fixed when scrolling up and down, so only the second column scrolls.

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/23333/) showing the problem.

How can I do this?

**--- SOLUTION ---**

Thanks for your suggestions, but I found a solution that works better for me, and without hardcoded padding etc.

CSS:

What I did, was to move the scrollbar from #main, and to .second-col. Now this second column is the only one that scrolls, and column 1 stays fixed.

```
#main {
   height: 200px;
   overflow-y:hidden;
}

.row {
  height: 100%;
}

.first-col {
  border-right: 1px solid;
  height: 100%;
}

.second-col {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  height: 100%
}
```

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/23366/) showing this.

Answer (score 1):

Give padding for second column

here is the code

Comment: Thanks, but the problem with this solution is, that I will need to hardcode a padding-left.

Comment: Here is the second column css                           https://jsfiddle.net/o4zyd70g/                                                                                            Let me know if it works for you

Answer (score 0):

You can use two DIV.

- The first is "fixed" with css (position : fixed)
- The second have not defined position

So the fisrt don't scrool with the second.

But if you want to 
put the DIV's side by side  : use "float" position on the second DIV.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this using percentages to avoid hardcoding in a margin.

```css
/* Latest compiled and minified CSS included as External Resource*/

/* Optional theme */
@import url('//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css');

body {
    margin: 10px;
}

#main {
   height: 200px;
   overflow-y:scroll;
}

.row {
  height: 100%;
}

.first-col {
  border-right: 1px solid;
  width: 19%;
  position:fixed;
}

.second-col{
  width:80%;
  margin-left:20%;
  top:0px;
  bottom:0px;
  left:0px;   
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-2 first-col">
       How to make this column fixed during scroll?
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-10 second-col">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis fermentum eget tellus et egestas. Donec augue sapien, aliquet vitae fermentum at, aliquet iaculis urna. Pellentesque dignissim eleifend erat vel tincidunt. Suspendisse et luctus augue, a facilisis ipsum. Donec dui leo, cursus pulvinar efficitur sed, eleifend non ex. Phasellus vestibulum erat at erat rhoncus ornare. Ut interdum auctor odio. Fusce lacinia arcu ligula, eu sollicitudin justo venenatis sed. Curabitur imperdiet lorem et massa bibendum consectetur. Nulla non tempus ligula. Proin vestibulum lacus at sodales sodales. Cras ultricies varius massa, et aliquam eros aliquet accumsan. Vivamus non neque nibh. Nullam ac tempor sem. Morbi mollis odio a nulla pulvinar euismod.

Aenean quis velit in nibh rutrum dapibus. Pellentesque sollicitudin diam consectetur quam egestas congue. Proin vestibulum porttitor purus, eget molestie velit finibus vitae. Nunc eget ultrices velit. Aenean vestibulum nunc ut commodo aliquet. Etiam at urna pellentesque libero vestibulum semper. Fusce accumsan urna ac ultricies laoreet. Duis mauris ligula, venenatis vitae egestas sed, bibendum vitae lorem. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos.

In pretium gravida varius. Mauris dui dui, pharetra at dolor nec, auctor molestie nibh. Vestibulum sagittis, metus ut hendrerit maximus, libero velit aliquet neque, ultrices rhoncus metus metus sit amet orci. Fusce in diam non dolor posuere scelerisque nec sed turpis. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Mauris at condimentum nibh. Sed sit amet mauris mauris. Nulla vestibulum molestie commodo. Fusce sit amet ipsum at ipsum rutrum ornare quis sollicitudin arcu. Nullam ut ipsum sed augue convallis volutpat sit amet sed mauris. Morbi quis augue quis augue iaculis lobortis sollicitudin in tortor.
    
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis fermentum eget tellus et egestas. Donec augue sapien, aliquet vitae fermentum at, aliquet iaculis urna. Pellentesque dignissim eleifend erat vel tincidunt. Suspendisse et luctus augue, a facilisis ipsum. Donec dui leo, cursus pulvinar efficitur sed, eleifend non ex. Phasellus vestibulum erat at erat rhoncus ornare. Ut interdum auctor odio. Fusce lacinia arcu ligula, eu sollicitudin justo venenatis sed. Curabitur imperdiet lorem et massa bibendum consectetur. Nulla non tempus ligula. Proin vestibulum lacus at sodales sodales. Cras ultricies varius massa, et aliquam eros aliquet accumsan. Vivamus non neque nibh. Nullam ac tempor sem. Morbi mollis odio a nulla pulvinar euismod.

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis fermentum eget tellus et egestas. Donec augue sapien, aliquet vitae fermentum at, aliquet iaculis urna. Pellentesque dignissim eleifend erat vel tincidunt. Suspendisse et luctus augue, a facilisis ipsum. Donec dui leo, cursus pulvinar efficitur sed, eleifend non ex. Phasellus vestibulum erat at erat rhoncus ornare. Ut interdum auctor odio. Fusce lacinia arcu ligula, eu sollicitudin justo venenatis sed. Curabitur imperdiet lorem et massa bibendum consectetur. Nulla non tempus ligula. Proin vestibulum lacus at sodales sodales. Cras ultricies varius massa, et aliquam eros aliquet accumsan. Vivamus non neque nibh. Nullam ac tempor sem. Morbi mollis odio a nulla pulvinar euismod.

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis fermentum eget tellus et egestas. Donec augue sapien, aliquet vitae fermentum at, aliquet iaculis urna. Pellentesque dignissim eleifend erat vel tincidunt. Suspendisse et luctus augue, a facilisis ipsum. Donec dui leo, cursus pulvinar efficitur sed, eleifend non ex. Phasellus vestibulum erat at erat rhoncus ornare. Ut interdum auctor odio. Fusce lacinia arcu ligula, eu sollicitudin justo venenatis sed. Curabitur imperdiet lorem et massa bibendum consectetur. Nulla non tempus ligula. Proin vestibulum lacus at sodales sodales. Cras ultricies varius massa, et aliquam eros aliquet accumsan. Vivamus non neque nibh. Nullam ac tempor sem. Morbi mollis odio a nulla pulvinar euismod.

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis fermentum eget tellus et egestas. Donec augue sapien, aliquet vitae fermentum at, aliquet iaculis urna. Pellentesque dignissim eleifend erat vel tincidunt. Suspendisse et luctus augue, a facilisis ipsum. Donec dui leo, cursus pulvinar efficitur sed, eleifend non ex. Phasellus vestibulum erat at erat rhoncus ornare. Ut interdum auctor odio. Fusce lacinia arcu ligula, eu sollicitudin justo venenatis sed. Curabitur imperdiet lorem et massa bibendum consectetur. Nulla non tempus ligula. Proin vestibulum lacus at sodales sodales. Cras ultricies varius massa, et aliquam eros aliquet accumsan. Vivamus non neque nibh. Nullam ac tempor sem. Morbi mollis odio a nulla pulvinar euismod.
    
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```